# Is there any conventional way to be notified of STL move and copy constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, move-semantics

I was wondering if there was a simple way to be notified of when STL containers themselves are copied or moved (without having to deal with the complexity of modifying or attempting to overload STL methods - as I imagine that to be cumbersome).

I use simple `std::cout` outputs to notify of moves and copies when I'm debugging single threaded applications (making sure my own reference types do what I intended).

I've been thinking about it for a while and I've only produced really, really, idiotic ideas (like overloading std::move to produce actual code so that it notifies of all attempts to create candidates for moving - lol). Or could you perhaps overload the real STL move and copy constructors and then make them invoke the real ones?

I'm thinking this could be useful for knowing where exactly copy elision is taking place, where things are actually being moved (and not decaying to a copy operation if the type is const).

Any insight would be interesting and appreciated.

Comment: Really terrible idea. Use capable profiling and static analysis tools instead.

Comment: Best idea off the top of my head would be a custom allocator but that would only work if you control declaration points of all instances you want to track.

Comment: Another note: Declaring anything inside `namespace std` (which includes your implementation of `std::move` etc.) results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Do you mean like exporting -g debug symbols and stepping through code to see where move constructors are invoked or?

Comment: @oldjohn1994 you might create either composition (preferred) or inheritance (discouraged) wrappers on top of standard containers, overloading copy- and move-constructors.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be notified at _runtime_ about these events (as they occur dynamically) or _statically_ at compile time, one per invocation in the source?

Comment: Or would it be sufficient to run the program once, and have a tool that reports all copies and moves?

Comment: As there is no way to counter close votes in favor of re-open until a question is already closed, and there is already one close vote registered, I hereby state my intent to vote to re-open this question if it is voted closed.

Comment: Note that pre-C++17, copy elision was a compiler decision, and might depend on the content of the copy ctor. Adding a non-trivial `std::cout <<` might very well turn an elided copy ctor into a non-elided ctor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *good* way to do this.  [HeroicKatora's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3750062/heroickatora) is the only possibility I'm aware of:  build a custom allocator that prints out messages when it is copy constructed and move constructed.  But there are issues...

To build a custom allocator, please feel free to use my [allocator boilerplate](http://howardhinnant.github.io/allocator_boilerplate.html) (no copyright, reference, or link needed).  This is just a skeleton allocator to help you get started.  It contains nothing special.

I've used this to create the following straw man allocator for this question:

```
template <class T>
class allocator
{
public:
    using value_type    = T;

    allocator() = default;
    allocator(allocator const&) = default;
    allocator(allocator&&)
    {
        std::cout << "container move construction\n";
    }

    template <class U> allocator(allocator<U> const&) noexcept {}

    value_type*  // Use pointer if pointer is not a value_type*
    allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        return static_cast<value_type*>(::operator new (n*sizeof(value_type)));
    }

    void
    deallocate(value_type* p, std::size_t) noexcept  // Use pointer if pointer is not a value_type*
    {
        ::operator delete(p);
    }

    allocator
    select_on_container_copy_construction() const
    {
        std::cout << "container copy construction\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

template <class T, class U>
bool
operator==(allocator<T> const&, allocator<U> const&) noexcept
{
    return true;
}

template <class T, class U>
bool
operator!=(allocator<T> const& x, allocator<U> const& y) noexcept
{
    return !(x == y);
}
```

When a container copy constructs, it is required to call `std::allocator_traits<your_allocator>::select_on_container_copy_construction()` to obtain the allocator for the copy constructed container.  If you don't implement this function in your allocator, `std::allocator_traits` just returns a copy of your allocator.  I've overridden this default behavior to output a message as well.

When a container move constructs, it is required to move construct the allocator.  So I've modified the `allocator` move constructor to print out a message.

The *problem* with this approach is that there is no requirement that the container move or copy your allocator only once!

Using `vector` as an example container, gcc provides the ideal results for this driver:

```
template <class T> using vector = std::vector<T, allocator<T>>;
template <class T> using deque = std::deque<T, allocator<T>>;

int
main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    std::cout << "Begin move\n";
    auto v2 = std::move(v);
    std::cout << "End move\n";
    std::cout << "Begin copy\n";
    auto v3 = v2;
    std::cout << "End copy\n";
}
```

gcc outputs:

```
Begin move
container move construction
End move
Begin copy
container copy construction
End copy
```

Visual Studio adds a gratuitous move construction to the copy:

```
Begin move
container move construction
End move
Begin copy
container copy construction
container move construction
End copy
```

And LLVM's libc++ doubles down on the move constructions:

```
Begin move
container move construction
container move construction
End move
Begin copy
container copy construction
container move construction
container move construction
End copy
```

In summary, an unsatisfactory "sort of". :-\

Comment: Should bug reports be filed against VC++ and libc++?

Comment: If you're interested in having this behavior change on these platforms, yes.  Just keep in mind this is a QOI issue, not a conformance issue.